# Why is my variable not changing its values?

Tags: python, variables

I have been making a text-based game. I have gotten to a point where I am trying to do a battle. I have the enemy's hp going down but when I hit it again, the enemy's hp is back to what I had originally set it as. I hope these help.

```
while do != 'hit rat with sword' or 'run away':
    enemyhp= 50
    enemyattack= [0,1,3]
    OldSwordattack= [0,1,4]
    print('What do you do?(attack or run away)')
    do=input()
    if do == 'run away':
        print('You can\'t leave mom like that!')
    if do == 'hit rat with sword':
        hit= random.choice(OldSwordattack)
        if hit == OldSwordattack[0]:
            print('Your swing missed')
            print('Enemy\'s HP=' + str(enemyhp))
        if hit == OldSwordattack[1]:
            print('Your swing hit, but very lightly.')
            enemyhp= enemyhp - 1
            print('Enemy\'s HP=' + str(enemyhp))
        if hit == OldSwordattack[2]:
            print('Your swing hit head on!')
            enemyhp= enemyhp - 4
            print('Enemy\'s HP=' + str(enemyhp))

>In front of mom you see a giant, yellow-teethed rat.
>What do you do?(attack or run away)
>hit rat with sword
>Your swing hit, but very lightly.
>Enemy's HP=49
>What do you do?(attack or run away)
>hit rat with sword
>Your swing hit, but very lightly.
>Enemy's HP=49
>What do you do?(attack or run away)
```

You see? The above is the program running. I do not see why the value is not being changed.

Comment: `x != y or z` doesn't compare `x` to `y` and `z`. It's parsed as `(x != y) or z`, which is not what you want. If you want to check whether something is one of several choices, you want `x not in (y, z)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are initializing it at the beginning of the iteration. So just move the

```
enemyhp= 50
```

before the while loop, like this

```
enemyhp= 50
while do != 'hit rat with sword' or 'run away':
```

Comment: This is only part of the problem.  the line `while do != 'hit rat with sword' or 'run away':` is flawed because 'run away' always evaluates to true, it's not comparing 'do' with both strings, it's comparing do with the first string and ORing it with an always true value.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I've extended your example program to include some more advanced language constructs. May you find it entertaining:  (Python 3)

```
import random
import re

def dice(s, reg=re.compile('(\d+d\d+|\+|\-|\d+)')):
    """
    Executes D+D-style dice rolls, ie '2d6 + 3'
    """
    total = 0
    sign = 1
    for symbol in reg.findall(s):
        if symbol == '+':
            sign = 1
        elif symbol == '-':
            sign = -1
        elif 'd' in symbol:
            d,s = [int(k) for k in symbol.split('d')]
            for i in range(d):
                total += sign * random.randint(1, s)
        else:
            total += sign * int(symbol)
    return total            

class Character():
    def __init__(self, name, attack, defense, health, weapon):
        self.name    = name
        self.attack  = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.health  = health
        self.weapon  = weapon

    def hit(self, target):
        if self.is_dead:
            print('{} is trying to become a zombie!'.format(self.name))
            return 0

        attack  = self.attack + self.weapon.attack_bonus + dice('2d6')
        defense = target.defense + dice('2d6')
        if attack > defense:
            damage = int(random.random() * min(attack - defense + 1, self.weapon.damage + 1))
            target.health -= damage
            print('{} does {} damage to {} with {}'.format(self.name, damage, target.name, self.weapon.name))
            return damage
        else:
            print('{} misses {}'.format(self.name, target.name))
            return 0

    @property
    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0

class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, name, attack_bonus, damage):
        self.name         = name
        self.attack_bonus = attack_bonus
        self.damage       = damage

def main():
    name = input("So, what's your name? ")

    me  = Character(name,         4, 6, 60, Weapon('Old Sword', 2, 4))
    mom = Character('Mom',        2, 2, 50, Weapon('Broom',     0, 1))
    rat = Character('Crazed Rat', 5, 2, 40, Weapon('Teeth',     1, 2))

    print("You are helping your mother clean the basement when a Crazed Rat attacks. "
          "You grab your Grandfather's sword from the wall and leap to defend her!")

    actors = {me, mom, rat}
    coward = False
    killer = None
    while (me in actors or mom in actors) and rat in actors:
        x = random.choice(list(actors))
        if x is mom:
            mom.hit(rat)
            if rat.is_dead:
                killer = mom
                actors -= {rat}
        elif x is rat:
            target = random.choice(list(actors - {rat}))
            rat.hit(target)
            if target.is_dead:
                actors -= {target}
                if target is mom:
                    print('Your mother crumples to the floor. AARGH! This rat must die!')
                    me.attack += 2
                else:
                    print('Well... this is awkward. Looks like Mom will have to finish the job alone...')
        else:  # your turn!
            print('Me: {}, Mom: {}, Rat: {}'.format(me.health, 0 if mom.is_dead else mom.health, rat.health))
            do = input('What will you do? [hit] the rat, [run] away, or [swap] weapons with Mom? ')
            if do == 'hit':
                me.hit(rat)
                if rat.is_dead:
                    killer = me
                    actors -= {rat}
            elif do == 'run':
                if me.health < 20:
                    actors -= {me}
                    coward = True
                else:
                    print("Don't be such a baby! Get that rat!")
            elif do == 'swap':
                me.weapon, mom.weapon = mom.weapon, me.weapon
                print('You are now armed with the {}'.format(me.weapon.name))
            else:
                print('Stop wasting time!')

    if rat.is_dead:
        if mom.is_dead:
            print('The rat is gone - but at a terrible cost.')
        elif me.is_dead:
            print("Your mother buries you with your trusty sword by your side and the rat at your feet.")
        elif coward:
            print("The rat is gone - but you'd better keep running!")
        elif killer is me:
            print("Hurrah! Your mother is very impressed, and treats you to a nice cup of tea.")
        else:
            print('Your mother kills the rat! Treat her to a nice cup of tea before finishing the basement.')
    else:
        print('I, for one, hail our new rat overlords.')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```